# How can I achieve this sound

Tags: sound-design

[Shake me Down](http://youtu.be/v27TRan1SBI) , by Cage the Elephant... What I wanna know is what's happening in the beginning of the song before the vocal comes in. It sounds like there is not only one guitar, and the delay effects are so nice. So if anyone can figure out whats happening there that would help a lot! Thanks.

Comment: It would help you a lot more as a sound designer to experiment and try to figure out how to make that sound yourself. If anyone just tells you how to make a sound, you haven't really learned anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! Actually I'm trying to reproduce a sound like this it's being a while. It seems though I'm failing on recognizing something over there. The idea is to know how to make that sound and there try to create something completely different from that, but with the mind a little more "aware" of what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well there are some long delays playing in the back but only thing i hear is 2 guitars spread 70%+ LR R - has a soft vibrato and sounds like a tele, L has a soft phaser or soft chorus a slow effect anyway. In the back where it goes "woo woo woo woo" it's a long delay playing , maybe a production thingy or another amp... Of course there might be some soft delays and reverbs in both guitars , it's an ambient intro anyway.., Someone could argue that the left channel is a delay, could be , but it's really easy to play it normally so , it doesn't really matter.

Generaly to hack a production you can start by splitting LR channels see what's going on,then take maybe an EQ and try to separate some regions.

--

When talking about ambience delay , reverb and the panpot are your friends.

The deeper you go you'll find help in soft effects such as chorus/phaser/flanger/rotary speakers/guitar doublers and stereo expanders.

After that point it's you and your mind alone, meaning that you can actually be as creative as you want , there are no guidelines. Start experimenting and try to break limits every time. You'll be able to create far more complex sounds than the one these guys did , im not saying it's bad but it's rather simple. :)